# Compilation issue in AEM 6,2

Tags: jsp, exception, compilation, aem, sling

Every time I run my AEM, I see below error in the logs. This comes up in every page, including Geometrixx pages.

```
10.05.2017 09:21:19.782 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1494422479763] GET /editor.html/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed (:\org/apache/jsp/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/admin/page\page_jsp.classtmp -> :\org/apache/jsp/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/admin/page\page_jsp.class)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:167)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:307)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:285)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:272)
```

...

Is there any specific issue with my laptop ? I tried installing it again an even restarted it many times. But still, the same error comes up.

I am running a vanilla AEM instance on 4502 without any web or app server running.

Comment: what is the version of Java you are using.? did any Felix bundles are **not active**?

Comment: Java 1.8-131.. .All bundles are active. I also tried recompiling all JSP's. Didnt help though

Comment: @RijuMahna it looks a bit like file system permission problems. `tmpFile.renameTo(classFile)` tries to rename a file but you get an `IOException`. Looks like AEM can't rename the file because of missing permissions.